# How to call an item from a list of items in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

i got a list like this, However my method isn't working, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
//My list of values 
List<string> values = new List { "$100","$300","$500"};
```

In my button1_click method

```
int i = 2;

object o = values[i];//i want the i to have value 2

this.button1.Text = Convert.ToString(i); //i want the button to text out the value from the values[i].
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(i);` shouldn't this be `Convert.ToString(o);`? Also, since `values` is `List<string>`, you can change your code to `var o = values[i];` (o is now a string, not object), and then you can write `this.button1.text = o;`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `this.button1.Text = values[i];`
this could be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting the wrong item.

```
this.button1.Text = Convert.ToString(i); //<---- i should be o
```

Change to:

```
this.button1.Text = Convert.ToString(o);
```

But you really shouldn't be converting from `string` to `object` and back to `string`.

Could simply just use:

```
this.button1.Text = values[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of strings, therefore there's no need to convert its value.

```
this.button1.Text = values[i];
```